# What level should I be before battling the Game Guadia?

Tags: retro-game-challenge

I've encountered a rather nasty Guadia while playing Retro Game Challenge's Guadia Quest, the "Game Guadia". Seeing how it looks like the game's (Retro Game Challenge's) antagonist, I was pretty sure I didn't stand a chance. I was correct.

My party members were level 6 when I attempted this, so I was wondering what level should I be before attempting to beat this Guadia?

What level should I be if I try to make a pact with this Guadia, seeing how that is a much greater challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Game Guadia's level is 25, so I would wager you'd want to have your party around level 20 before you attempt defeating it. I didn't have much trouble taking down a Lost Guadia (level 15) in the Dungeon of Darkness while my party was all around level 10, so 5 levels should be a safe bet. However, with enough items, I'm sure you could fudge those numbers a little lower.